# Function calling a function; why does this return NoneType instead of reading file?

Tags: python-2.7, file, nonetype

After reading about file objects in Pydoc as well as seeing how functions can call functions, I rewrote one of Zed Shaw's LPTHW scripts in an attempt to understand how it works.

Here is the code:

```
def open_file(f):
    open(f)

def read_file(f):
    f.read()

read_file(open_file('test.txt'))
```

And here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in read_file
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

And yet this works fine:

```
input_file = 'test.txt'

print open(input_file).read()
```

Why does the function calling a function version return NoneType instead of reading the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `open_file()` function doesn't actually return anything. What you want is:

```
def open_file(f):
    return open(f)
```

A function that reaches its end without explicitly returning a value returns `None`, so you're getting the exception because your code is trying to execute `read_file(None)`, which in turn tries to execute `None.read()`. `None` objects do not have a `read()` method.

Comment: I understand now; it is the simplest things that get me sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
def open_file(f):
    return open(f)

def read_file(f):
    print f.read()

read_file(open_file('test.txt'))
```

Which gives the output of:

```
Mary had a little lamb.
Its fleece was white as snow.
It was also very tasty.
```

Comment: Curious why the change of accepted answer. Answerers are encouraged to provide an explanation of what the error is and why it caused the observed behavior, which is what I did.

Comment: Per my understanding posters are also encouraged to provide their own answer when possible. Or am I misunderstanding? No slight meant.

Comment: Nothing wrong with answering your own question, but note that it doesn't float your answer to the top or give you (or anyone) reputation, so there's usually not much point to doing it unless there are no other answers or any other answers are seriously lacking. If other answers *are* lacking, a comment to request additional information would be a good first step.